# how to pass a command to powershell that include curly braces in it?

Tags: powershell

You can pass a powershell command to powershell.exe like this:

```
PowerShell -Command {Get-EventLog -LogName security}
```

But what if the command contains <kbd>{</kbd> or <kbd>}</kbd>? Such as:

```
dir z:\test -fi "*.tmp" -r | ?{$_.creationtime -le (Get-Date).adddays(-30)} | del
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

another possibility is to encode your command :

```
$command = "dir z:\test -fi '.tmp' -r | ?{$_.creationtime -le (Get-Date).adddays(-30)} | del "
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)

powershell.exe -encodedCommand $encodedCommand
```

Answer (score 2):

The command parameter can accept a script block as well as a string, in your top example {} denote a script block. So just enclose your command in "" instead of {}.

```
PowerShell.exe -Command "dir z:\test -fi "*.tmp" -r | ?{$_.creationtime -le (Get-Date).adddays(-30)} | del"
```

The only thing to remember is that if you specify it as a string like above, Command has to be the last argument you specify since everything after it is interpreted as the command you want to run.

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
PowerShell.exe -Command "dir z:\test -fi "*.tmp" -r | ?{$_.creationtime -le (Get-Date).adddays(-30)} | del"
```

Answer (score 0):

using Invoke-Expression can be an option

```
PowerShell -Command {Invoke-Expression "dir z:\test -fi `"*.tmp`" -r | ?{`$_.creationtime -le (Get-Date).adddays(-30)} | del"}
```